# Stop Watch program

Tags: java, swing

I have a stop watch program due for my Java I class, it's from Java foundations 3rd edition pp 6.22 and i'm having trouble getting it to run. I'm not sure where i went wrong. Any help deciphering the issue would be appreciated! The program is supposed to have a 3 button setup and the stop watch counts in seconds, nothing fancy. I'm having issues with the buttons themselves, I can't get them to start, stop and reset the timer. I'm using Jgrasp as my compiler, and it all compiles fine. No errors to report. I'm not sure if i have my if /else statements right or if i left something out that's not letting the timer begin counting. Heres what the assignment is: Design and implement an application that works as a stop watch. Include the display that shows the time in seconds as it increments. Include buttons that allow the user to start and stop the time, and reset the display to zero.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Assignment_6_22_Panel extends JPanel
{
  private JButton start, stop, reset;
  private JLabel label;
  private JPanel buttonPanel;
  private Timer timer; 
  private int time = 0;
  private final int DELAY = 1000;


public Assignment_6_22_Panel()
{
  label = new JLabel("Time: " + time);
  setBackground(Color.white);

  start = new JButton("Start");
  stop = new JButton("Stop");
  reset = new JButton("Reset");

  ButtonListener listener = new ButtonListener();
  TimeListener watchListener = new TimeListener();

  timer = new Timer(DELAY, watchListener);

  start.addActionListener(listener);
  stop.addActionListener(listener);
  reset.addActionListener(listener);



  buttonPanel = new JPanel();
  buttonPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 150));
  buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
  buttonPanel.add(start);
  buttonPanel.add(stop);
  buttonPanel.add(reset);
  add(buttonPanel);
  add(label);

}


private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
{

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
  {
     if (event.getSource() == start)
        timer.start();

     else
         if (event.getSource() == stop)
            timer.stop();
         else
            time = 0;

  }
 }

private class TimeListener implements ActionListener
{

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
  {

        label = new JLabel("Your Time: " + time);


  }
 }
}
```

Here's the adjoining code

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import javax.swing.*;

 public class Assignment_6_22
 {
 //-----------------------------------------------------------------
 //  Displays the main frame of the program.
 //-----------------------------------------------------------------
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
  JFrame frame = new JFrame("Stop Watch");
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

  frame.getContentPane().add(new Assignment_6_22_Panel());

  frame.pack();
  frame.setVisible(true);
  }
 }
```

Comment: What sort of trouble are you having then?

Comment: Explain your problem. What does your program do? What was it supposed to do? Do you get errors? If so, add stack traces, and mark the place in the code where the error occurs.

Comment: When you get an error, please include the exact error message instead of just saying "there is some error somewhere". Error messages contain important information that gives a hint about what is wrong and where.

Comment: sorry edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Timer` code and `ButtonListener` code works just fine, the problem is in your `TimerListener`...

```
private class TimeListener implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        label = new JLabel("Your Time: " + time);

    }
}
```

You're creating a new instance of `JLabel` each time the `Timer` triggers, which has no relationship to what is been displayed on the screen, instead, you need to set the text of the prexisting label.

Also, no where to you actually update the value of `time` to show the passage of time...

```
private class TimeListener implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        time++;
        label.setText("Your Time: " + time);

    }
}
```

When you `reset` the `Timer`, you should also make sure that you update the `label`

```
private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if (event.getSource() == start) {
            timer.start();
        } else if (event.getSource() == stop) {
            timer.stop();
        } else {
            time = 0;
            label.setText("Your Time: " + time);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i'm very much new to this site and to Java. This was extremely helpful. Thank you again MadProgrammer!